# Remove underline gmail hyperlink from outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail

Is it possible to remove blue hyperlink underline in gmail when I copy web page content to outlook and send to gmail?

There is any underlined link when I paste text to outlook new mail window, but when i open sent letter from gmail i see that ugly blue underline. Than line appears only in desktop gmail, in mobile gmail app there is no underline.

I tried everything that I can find in google.

This is my code:

```
<style>
  a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
</style>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="69" style="height:69px;" valign="middle" width="600"><a href="mylink" target="_blank" style="color:#040400;text-decoration: none;"><h2 style="text-align: center;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Title</h2></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This style on  `h2` `text-decoration: none;`

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="69" style="height:69px;" valign="middle" width="600"><a href="mylink" target="_blank" style="color:#040400;text-decoration: none;"><h2 style="text-align: center;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;">Title</h2></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: still see underline